# Templates are not working for custom frontend modules

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have a module Namespace/Search, which was installed when I got here. I took <[namespace]_index_index> contents from it and have it here. This is from a currently working module.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
 </reference>
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="search/search" name="search" template="ifi_search/index.phtml" />
</reference>
```

I've used the above as a template for the helloworld module.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml" />
</reference>
```

With the second example I'm left with an entirely blank page, developer mode is turned on. To the extend of my knowledge on the topic I don't have any other information to present for debugging. If there's anything that would be useful if I added, please comment. I'm unsure if I can reproduce this problem at this point.

Comment: Per the warning on the top of the page, that article contains some dodgey information, and even if it didn't the information is out of date. That said, per @benmarks below, if you're replacing the root block like that and Magento lets you do it, you need a output="toHtml" attribute.

Comment: I'm running an older version of Magento so I don't see the article being told being the problem. Rather than copying mine I copied part of the code from the second example and edited, I must have removed the output="toHtml" on accident and not realized it. I have tried several different variations of what I have up there currently, as well as several different methods in the IndexController. What I found did work was using <action method="setTemplate">page.phtml<//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `output` attribute in your block declaration:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" template="simple_page.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
```

This marks the block as an output block and sets the block rendering method to `toHtml()`. Output blocks are rendering entry points in the call to `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion on the output="toHtml". I didn't paste the right code out of the article. I will update the question to reflect the output, but it still does the exact same thing.